# Input Buffer holds old input despite FlushConsoleInputBuffer MASM

Tags: winapi, assembly, input, x86, buffer

I wrote a program that processes the array and I need to check the correctness of the input. If you enter along with numbers and letters, then the input command loops and does not allow you to enter data, I decided to do the cleaning of the buffer before each input, but the problem remained

```
S1:invoke   WriteConsole, h_output, ADDR ComSizeMas, Len_ComSize, ADDR nWrite, 0 
   invoke FlushConsoleInputBuffer,h_input
   invoke      crt_scanf,  ADDR format_size_buf, ADDR Size_buf     
   CMP Size_buf,1
   JL S1
   CMP Size_buf,100
   JG S1
```

Comment: The console input buffer may be a lower level windows thing, while scanf is a C library function so it may be reading from the C stdio buffer.

Comment: you need call `fflush(__iob_func())` instead `FlushConsoleInputBuffer`

Answer (score 1):

`scanf[_s]` read data to internal crt buffer. call `FlushConsoleInputBuffer` have no effect on it. instead we need call [`fflush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa272686(v=vs.100)#MainContent) on stdin stream

> If the stream is open for input, fflush clears the contents of the
>   buffer

so in *c/c++* code we need `fflush(__iob_func())` call.

demo example *c/c++*

```
ULONG __cdecl GetNumberc()
{
    ULONG n;
    while (!scanf_s("%u", &n))
    {
        if (fflush(__iob_func())) break;

        printf("invalid number\n");
    }

    return n;
}
```

for *x86* asm

```
extern __imp__fflush : DWORD, 
       __imp____iob_func : DWORD, 
       __imp__scanf_s : DWORD,
       __imp__printf : DWORD

.const
format_number DB "%u",0
invalid_number DB "invalid number",10,0

.code

_GetNumber proc
    sub esp,4
@@0:
    push esp
    push offset format_number
    call __imp__scanf_s
    add esp,8
    test eax,eax
    jnz @@1

    call __imp____iob_func
    push eax
    call __imp__fflush
    add esp,4
    test eax,eax
    jnz @@1
    push offset invalid_number
    call __imp__printf
    add esp,4
    jmp @@0
@@1:
    mov eax,[esp]
    add esp,4
    ret
_GetNumber endp
```

for *x64* asm

```
extern __imp_fflush : QWORD, 
       __imp___iob_func : QWORD, 
       __imp_scanf_s : QWORD,
       __imp_printf : QWORD

.const
format_number DB "%u",0
invalid_number DB "invalid number",10,0

.code

GetNumber proc
    sub rsp,28h
@@0:
    lea rdx,[rsp+30h]
    lea rcx,format_number
    call __imp_scanf_s
    test eax,eax
    jnz @@1

    call __imp___iob_func
    mov rcx,rax
    call __imp_fflush
    test eax,eax
    jnz @@1
    lea rcx,invalid_number
    call __imp_printf
    jmp @@0
@@1:
    mov eax,[rsp+30h]
    add rsp,28h
    ret
GetNumber endp
```